# Is setContentView method is a method of AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

I am learning to develop an android app and while developing an android app. I came across a method `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `MainActivity.java`. The `MainActivity` extends `AppCompactActivity`.

So `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is the one of the method found in `AppCompactView`?

Comment: Yes it is inherited from Parent class in this case immediate parent is `AppCompatActivity` and it came all the from upper level Class `Activity`.. Press `Ctrl+Click` on method it will show declaration .

Comment: @ADM Thanks for the comment, Previously I searched the source code of classes on google. This `ctrl+click` is great.